# Expression for Linq between 2 classes in a 1 to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq

I have a couple of Class:

```
 public class Op
{
    [Key]
    public int OpId { get; set; }
    private OpportunitiesDb db = new OpportunitiesDb();

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Opportunity title is required")]
    [DisplayName("Opportunity Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tags")]
    public ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
 }


 public class Tags
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OpId { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }

}
```

I have 1 class of Type OpId. A Op class can have many Tags (One to Many relationship).

This OpId has a tag let's suppose "Water"

Now I need to find in the tags all Ops that has "Water" as Tag.
The db contexts have the 2 tables (Ops and Tags).

The action of my controller is:
        public async Task QueryTags(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("IdNotPresent", "Error");
            }

```
        Op SelectedOp = db.Opportunities.Find(id);
        //get tags for ID.
        var Tags = db.Tags
            .Where(s => s.OpId == id);



        var model =
            from r in db.Tags
            where (r.OpId == id)
            select r;
        return PartialView(await model.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed is this search, this will bring All the Ops that have the same tag in string Query var:

```
var AllOpsWithTagQuery = from r in db.Tags
           where(r.Tag.StartsWith(Query))
           join o in db.Opportunities on r.OpId equals o.OpId
           select o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Tag`

```
from r in db.Tags
join o in db.Ops on r.OpId equals o.OpId
group o by r.Tag into ops
select ops
```

filter by tag to get the Ops you're looking for

Comment: This is not working for me. It should bring all Ops that has a given "Tag"